# MacOS High Sierra - How to format readonly pendirve?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

I have a HP 32GB v210w pendrive and I somehow made it to read only halfway transferring the file. I tried every diskutil method and few terminal methods but it's all in vain. The pendrive works fine but it's read only. Kindly help me out on how to format it.

This is one of such errors that I get.

[image]

Comment: There's a full workup of this answer on https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only but basically, if the drive reported a write error it may have triggered the firmware write-protect. This is essentially irreversible. Bin it & buy a new one.

Answer (score 1):

sudo diskutil unmountdisk force disk2

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk2 bs=1024 count=1024

link:-

> https://superuser.com/questions/1019759/how-can-i-force-format-read-only-usb-drive-in-osx-el-capitan

Comment: Hey, I got this error when I tried it.
dd: /dev/disk2: Permission denied